# SSL Между клиентом и сервероом на C#

Tags: c#, tcp

у меня есть два приложения КЛИЕНТ и СЕРВЕР на c# которые работают по протоколу TCP. Мне нужно, что бы они работали в режиме SSL. Как можно создать сертификат на C# который будет нормально работать с классом SSLStream? У меня вылетает ошибка *SSL серверного режима  должен использовать сертификат с соответствующим закрытым ключом.*
Код клиент сервер брал со статьи от Microsoft.